# Error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 15,Token in error = User ]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I'm working on my first local SQL Server CE database (`.sdf`) project. I've created a table in the database and added some columns.

Now I want to create my first statement but I get the following error:

> error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset =
>   15,Token in error = User ]
>
> Error on that line: `SqlCeDataReader sqlDataReader =
>   cmd.ExecuteReader();

Code:

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StarterSite"].ConnectionString;
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM User WHERE LOWER(bname) = LOWER(@0)", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("0", bname);

        SqlCeDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string retbname = sqlDataReader["password"].ToString();
        sqlDataReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `User` is a keyword, either change the table name or use double quotes: `"User"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
"SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE LOWER(bname) = LOWER(@0)"
```

instead of:

```
"SELECT * FROM User WHERE LOWER(bname) = LOWER(@0)"
```

user is a keyword in sql server!